# Does windows xp contain GdiPlus.dll?

Tags: deployment, windows-xp, gdi+

I have a question about deploying application, my application need gdiplus.dll for load images.
Does windows xp contain GdiPlus.dll as default?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is a guarantee, but in my experience it has almost always been there already.  There is a [GDI+ redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6A63AB9C-DF12-4D41-933C-BE590FEAA05A&displaylang=en):

Edit:  Here they state quite plainly that GDI+ "[is included in Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx)".  So unless you are deploying to one of those other operating systems, it sounds like you can assume that on Windows XP that it is already there.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [DLL Help Database](http://support.microsoft.com/dllhelp/) will tell you for each DLL exactly which versions of which products ship it. You can search it for your specific DLL and see, for example, what is the earliest OS version that ships with it.

Comment: DLL Help Database _`was retired on February 8, 2010 and is no longer accessible.'_